# Dynamically initialize a ng-model directive

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

I'm dynamically building a form with angular depending of the kind of input:

```
<div ng-controller="formController" ng-repeat="field in formFields" ng-switch="field.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="text">
        <!-- Something -->
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="dropdown">
        <myDirective my-data="field.param" ng-model="field.model"></myDirective>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've got two problems with my directive which builds a custom dropdown input:

1. Ng-model directive interprated the name `field.model` as plain text, whereas I would like the attributs `ng-model="field.model"` would be replaced by the value contained into `field.model`. Curly brackets don't seems to work here. Any idea?
2. How to let the ng-model value accessible both in my form controller, and into my custom directive's controller?

Exemple of a field object:

```
{
    label : "Name",
    model : "employeeName",
    type : "dropdown",
    param : {
        dropdownArray : result,
        dropdownName : 'Nom',
        dropdownFieldValue : 'nameUUID',
        dropdownVisibleValue : [ 'employeeSS', 'employeeName' ]
    }    
}
```

Then in my controller I should be able to access this dropdown value with: `$scope.employeeName`.

Comment: what does the field object look like? are you creating it on the fly, in the view?

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand I just add an exemple of this object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It sounds like you're accessing `field.model` via the attributes input parameter supplied to the `link` function in your directive. Instead, you should be accessing it via the scope variable.

   ```
   link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
     // attributes.ngModel will yield 'field.model'
     // scope.ngModel will contain the actual value of field.model
   }
   ```
2. If you don't explicitly define an isolate scope for your directive, then `ng-model` assigned to `field.model` should be available in your directive via the scope variable as I mentioned above.

   ```
   scope: false  // This is the default

   // Define an isolate scope with field.model available through scope.ngModel
   scope: {
     ngModel: '='
   }
   ```

Hope that helps.